# How to stop Eclipse making new line between array instantiation and its values ( Ctrl + Shift + F)?

Tags: java, eclipse, formatting

When I instantiate an array in Eclipse like this:

```
int[] intArray = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
```

and then press **Ctrl+Shift+F**   Eclipse formats my code like this:

```
int[] intArray = new int[] 
{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
```

how I can configure Eclipse to leave variables on the same line with its in instantiation?

Tnx!

Comment: This is a setting in the formatter.  The default is not to break there so either you have a very long line, or you have changed the defaults.

Comment: Is this the exact source you work with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to `Window` > `Preferences` > `Java` > `Code Style` > `Formatter` > `Edit` > `Braces` > `Array initializers` and set it to `Same line`.

Comment: That's the thing! Array initializers was always set to "Same line", but my Eclipse is still drops values to next line! :(

Comment: @It_Does_Not_Matter Go to `Window > Preferences > Java > Code Style > Formatter > Edit > Comments > Line Wrapping > Maximum line width` and increase that value.

Comment: Nope, sorry, but it does not help! There is something over it that creates new line..

Comment: probably there is some bug in my Eclipse, it will be good to reinstall it, but there too many configurations. I will leave it the way it is. Thanks.